# Problem with Extrude in Blender 3.6

Tags: extrude, loop

After extruding I get this type edges. But I want the old edge loop to be at the same place
as it were. But when I extrude this the old loop gets messed up and also changes the position and a new loop is generated at the place of the old one.
So I want both(the one before extrude and the one after extrude) the loops to be at the same place.
What shall I do to fix this?
This is the link to video I am watching to learn:-https://youtu.be/zwf86kHwNoE
timestamp:- 6:35
[Video is from Blender Arts channel.]
[image: (This pic is taken after extrude.)The yellow loop on the left side is the position where I want both the old loop and the extruded loop. And the first loop after the yellow loop is the loop is which is generated after extrude which I want to be at the same position as that of yellow loop.]

This is the link of my file: [image]

Comment: I think we'll need to see your Blend file to work out exactly what's going on. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link to it and then edit your question and paste the link into it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Just after hitting E for extrude the new loop is formed inside the old loop and this also messes some part of old loop. So what can I do so that the new loop will be generated at the same place as that of old loop without affecting the old loop. @John Eason

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what's causing that in your Blend file, but you can select the vertex on the original loop and move it up a bit to get rid of the distortion. It's probably an effect of the subdiv modifier at a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have inconsistent Normals:

[image]

- Display with Overlays > 'Face Orientation'
- Flip with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> 'Recalculate' 'Inside' or 'Outside'.. whichever takes you to all blue, viewed from the front.

I quite like to tweak a modelling copy of my ( Edit > Preferences > **Theme** > 3D Viewport ) to something akin to this:

[image]

.. which means it's comfortable to leave the 'Face Orientation' overlay on all the time. Then you always know which way your faces are pointing.